# Perl CAM:PDF extract pdf language

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm extracting PDF metadata using `CAM::PDF`. I have one last requirement which is to get the PDF Reading language. I need to know if it is English, French, etc.

```
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filePath) || die "<br/>Error: $filePath";
my $info = $pdf->getValue($pdf->{trailer}->{Info});
```

I'm not seeing any additional info regarding language type when I dump the `$info` variable. Is this not possible to get the PDF Language?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a content language was commonly recorded in PDFs? I'm not aware that generators include this information. Do you have an example for a PDF with language metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As amon said, I don't think you can find this information in metadata.

You can check the [Lingua::Identify](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Lingua-Identify-0.56/lib/Lingua/Identify.pm) module.

Comment: Thanks amon, I found this module very useful and accomplished my goal.